# Jsonp call to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, javascript

If I try, like this way:

```
        $.ajax({
       jsonp: false,
       jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
       type: 'GET',
       url: "http://79.141.150.167/geoserver/xxx/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=xxx:business_service&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
       async: false,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
       }
    });
```

My browser tells me following:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://79.141.150.167/geoserver/xxx/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&requ…tputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson&_=1393412236410".
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (ows:1)

...what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
outputFormat=text/javascript
```

with

```
outputFormat=application/json
```

and try again, the request should be ok.

Comment: ok! That worked out fine. I'm having now an error on that ows file I get (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ) but the file is there so I think (hope) I can work around that. Thank you!